# PHPunit command line variable on windows giving trouble

Tags: php, windows-7, phpunit

I installed PHPunit via the commandline and added it to my path variables.
I then tried to see if it will run, but I got a weird error.
[image: CMD screen]

Must be something in some file that I didn't configure correctly, but there are over 800 lines in all the PHPUnit folder that reference to that folder, so I'm at a loss as to which one it is. Most will be for PHP scripts instead of the commandline, but I'm not sure where to look.

This is the variable. This file actually exists, just phpunit and no extension.
[image: variable path]

The contents(left out the comments):

```
#!c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.1\php.exe
<?php
//whole lot of comments...

if (strpos('c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.1\php.exe', '@php_bin') === 0) {
    set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
}

require_once 'PEAR/PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php';

PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addFileToFilter(__FILE__, 'PHPUNIT');

require 'PEAR/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php';

define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD', 'PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main');

PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
?>
```

The relative paths are correct, since the phpunit file is located in the php-map and PEAR is the submap containing all installed PEAR packages.

Comment: Can be closed, solution found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.1\pear\phpunit` or `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.1\phpunit`?

Comment: What do you mean by asking that? On my install, both paths you posted exist. The first is a map, the second is a file.

Comment: what path is getting executed when you run `phpunit`?  what does it try to do with `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.1\pear\phpunit`?

Comment: Please look at the second screenshot. That is the file which is called, since that is the location which is set.

Comment: Nevermind, there was a wrong path listed in the phpunit.bat file.